# How to put a large string pointed to by a pointer to a buffer

Tags: c, pointers

I am a beginner and I need to know how to put a large string like a page full of string pointed to by a pointer, into a buffer.
for example, if `pointer p->helpPage`
I want to put the entire content of the help page in `char buffer[500]`

Please help.

Comment: Why complete text is bold?

Comment: I simply put it in bold. I wasn't sure what that would signify

Comment: Please post your "large string".  I suspect it is either more than 500 characters or has some special encoding, else you would not be having this trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `strncpy`.

```
const char *src = "Some string";
const int BUF_SIZE = 64;
char buf[BUF_SIZE];
strncpy(buf, src, sizeof buf);
buf[BUF_SIZE-1] = '\0';
```

`strncpy`, unlike `strcpy`, takes an additional parameter; the size of the supplied buffer.  This helps to combat buffer overflows.

Comment: `sizeof(buf)` is the size of the buffer in bytes, but `strncpy` needs the number of characters.  If multibyte chars are used then this will overflow `buf`

Comment: @Steve: I suppose it's a good thing then that `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1.  There is no such thing as a "multi-byte char"

Comment: Fair point, I think I've gotten used to seeing people using `wchar_t` in MSVC and have been scarred by that.  I appreciate this is a C question and MSVC is not a C compiler though!

Comment: @Steve: Hehe, I try to stay away from the Windows API... msve is C though, just an old standard (C89).

Comment: I tried doing strcpy(buffer, pointer)
got an error while doing a make

Comment: @user2655793: You'll have to elaborate.  Also, again, use `strncpy`.

Comment: This is what I am doing.
 char fahadstr[500];
 strncpy(fahadstr, cntrlText, sizeof(fahadstr));
 printf("\n\n\n%s\n\n\n",fahadstr);

Comment: @user2655793: And the error message is...?  Did you include the header?

Comment: Yes the header files are included properly. Getting the following errors:
AutoUSC.c
c:\maser_usc\espada_1.4\msc\edk2\UscPkg\Lib\AutoUSCLib\AutoUSC.c(1436) : error C2143: syntax error :
 missing ';' before 'type'
c:\maser_usc\espada_1.4\msc\edk2\UscPkg\Lib\AutoUSCLib\AutoUSC.c(1437) : error C2065: 'fahadstr' : u
ndeclared identifier
c:\maser_usc\espada_1.4\msc\edk2\UscPkg\Lib\AutoUSCLib\AutoUSC.c(1437) : warning C4047: 'function' :
 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
c:\maser_usc\espada_1.4\msc\edk2\UscPkg\Lib\Auto

Comment: @user2655793: Ok, so you have other code in there which is broken. I can't help you without seeing it.

Comment: without my 3 lines of code. everything seems to work fine

Comment: @user2655793: You can show me all of your code or you can assume the compiler is broken.

Comment: okay its working now.
its printing just one letter like 'm' or 'o' or 'p'
if I use printf(L"%ls", fahadstr); then its printing half the page

Comment: From your error message you are building a UEFI driver/application. EDK2 is the EFI Developers Kit. That uses UTF16 strings and does not typically use a standard C library.  That's important information for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy).  E.g.

```
int size = sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]);
strncpy(buffer, p->helpPage, size);
buffer[size-1] = '\0';
```

In the above call, `strncpy` is asked to copy only 499 characters which ensures the `buffer` is null terminated.  It also handles characters over one byte (e.g. `wchar_t` on Windows).

There is also `strcpy`, but if `p->helpPage` has more data in it than your `buffer` it will cause a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)

Comment: You probably should null terminate explicitly. Arrays are not initialized to 0 in C unless you do it yourself.  Glad you added though as even I forgot to in my example.

Comment: @EdS. good point, corrected answer.

Answer (score 0):

A page can be considered as a array of pointers where each pointer points to each line or sentence. so if you want to copy a particular line or sentence then you could use,
    strncpy(buff, p->helpPage, n);
if you know the size of each line or you could get a char and copy the char to another buffer till you get a newline or a dot.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [`strcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) to copy your pointer `p->helpPage` to your buffer `buffer`:

```
strcpy(buffer, p->helpPage);
```

Comment: I already have a pointer pointing to my helpPage. I am writing the code as follows:
    strcpy(buffer, pointer);
I am getting an error while doing a make

Comment: @user2655793 share your code in order to help you

Comment: I have just written these three lines of code:

 char fahadstr[500];          
 strncpy(fahadstr, cntrlText, sizeof(fahadstr));         
 printf("%s",fahadstr);

Comment: cntrlText is the pointer pointing to my helpPage.